# How to set multiple functions in one onClick

Tags: android, kotlin

I have to create a simple login app where it should open a new activity when the correct credentials are inputted and shows a toast message if it's wrong.

I've tried changing the order around and still no luck

```
val username = text_input_username.text.toString()
val password = text_input_password.text.toString()

con_btn.isAllCaps = false
con_btn.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(this, Login::class.java)
    val message = "Wrong Credentials"

    if((username == "admin") && (password == "1234")){
        startActivity(intent)
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
      }
  }
```

The code provided will print the toast message no matter what I put, and if the if the statement is there it won't open the new activity page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the text retrieval to `setOnClickListener` event. Then it's going to work. With your current code, you were retrieving the text way before the user would click the button so you were always getting the older text and the `if` condition was failing.

```
con_btn.isAllCaps = false
con_btn.setOnClickListener {
  val username = text_input_username.text.toString().trim()
  val password = text_input_password.text.toString().trim()

  if((username == "admin") && (password == "1234")){
      val intent = Intent(this, Login::class.java)
      startActivity(intent)
  } else {
      val message = "Wrong Credentials"
      Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
   }
}
```

Also added `.trim()` function to remove any whitespaces.